# How to enumerate the smart card related certificates from the windows store using c#?

Tags: c#, cryptography

```
store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
//
// Retrieve the certificates from the store.
//
X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

//
// Find all the certificates of the store.
//
fCollection_Date = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(
                                                               X509FindType.FindByTimeValid,
                                                               DateTime.Now,
                                                               false);
//
// Display the listed certificates in the UI form
//
sCollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
                                                     fCollection_Date,
                                                     "Select Certificate",
                                                     "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate",
                                                      X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
```

The following code will find the certificates in the windows certificate store and list out the certificates by time validity.

Is there any method to list certificates that are related to smart card only.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: maybe you could check if you can find something out by trying to access the private key. That should still be on your smart card. The certificates may well have been copied into your store by the time you access them. That would of course only work for end-user (leaf) certificates for which you do have the private key.